Search nested array of objects in JSON object
I need to make a query to return an entire row on the condition of a substring search. This search must match a column called 'movies' and it is a JSON Object within it, inside this object is an array called cast. This array contains cast member objects which have a name field.
The search aims to match a substring search to cast member names. If there is a match return the movie row.
Data structure:
`movie`: {
    `cast`: [
        {`name`: "Cleveland"},
        {`name`: "Joe"},
        {`name`: "Quagmire"}
    ]
}

I'm using whereRaw queries but I'm probably not on the right track. I think JSON array iteration may not be supported for SQLite, are there any other ways around?

Why are you storing JSON inside an RDBMS? You should normalize your data first. Why haven't you done that?

Use json_extract() again after json_each(json_extract()) to extract each x and y and aggregate:
SELECT f.id, 
   MIN(json_extract(value, '$.x')) x, 
   MIN(json_extract(value, '$.y')) y
FROM features f, json_each(json_extract(f.data, '$.A.B.coordinates'))
GROUP BY f.id

See the demo.

You can extract the rows using json_each and do a LIKE on value->'$.name':
select
  *
from
  things
where
  exists (
    select
      1
    from
      json_each(movie, '$.cast')
    where
      value->'$.name' like '%land%'
  );

Input:
create table things (movie text);

insert into things (movie) values ('{
    "cast": [
        {"name": "Cleveland"},
        {"name": "Joe"},
        {"name": "Quagmire"}
    ]
}');

Output with %land%:
{
    "cast": [
        {"name": "Cleveland"},
        {"name": "Joe"},
        {"name": "Quagmire"}
    ]
}

Output with '%random%': no rows.
